# In VB2008Express, how do I use reuseable code files as in VB6

Tags: vb.net, vb6

In VB6 I had (example) the following directories:

CommonCode

Parser

OrbitalDynamics

DnD

RelativisticBang

The first is standard inclusions I use (constants.vb, science.vb, constAstro.vb, DnD.vb...) while the others are projects who all use one or more of the common code files.

If I loaded OrbitalDynamics and, while in it, added a new constant in constants.vb then the next time I loaded the others, they also had the new constant immediately available.

I've rebuilt the common code files for VB2008Exp.  I'm now trying to rebuild some of the projects.  The problem is that I've not found a way to bring in the common code files.  Every time I've tried it's *copied* them into the project rather than referenced them.  Copying is, obviously, useless for the idea of *common code*.

Hopefully someone out there knows what I've missed, or knows some other method of using common code files in VB2008Exp.  I can do this sort of thing in CPP, in C (both in Linux), and in VB6, but so far VB2008Exp has been very intractable.

Comment: You can [add the external file as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862185/visual-studio-using-external-files-without-copying-them). An alternative it to compile the shared code into an assembly DLL then just reference that in your projects.

Comment: Many thanks.  Looked all over for that silly option and didn't see it.  It looks like it does exactly what I want.  We'll see how it goes on my rebuilds.